# Calling a KDB function in a loop

Tags: kdb

I have a function that returns meta of a table. I am trying to call it in a loop but instead of meta, one of the parameters is returned. Is my syntax wrong?

```
 h: hopen `:host:port:id:pass
 tabs:h"exec distinct tables from configTable"
 getMeta:first h({`funcName;;;`metas};[`tickType;]each tabs)
```

I get `metas when I run the above even though the function works when individual parameters are passed in instead of a loop.

Value of tabs

```
`table1`table2`table3`table4`table5
```

Function call for one table that works

```
h(`funcName;`tickType;`tableName;`metas)
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you're trying to do I think you'd want:

```
h@/:(`funcName;`tickType;;`metas)each tabs
```

or as a single sync call it could be:

```
h({funcName[`tickType;x;`metas]}';tabs)
```

Your syntax wasn't right and what you were sending to the server was essentially:

```
h({`metas};tabs)
```

which explains why it was returning  `` `metas ``

Answer (score 1):

The below code shows how you can loop over a remote function call. A few notes:

- might want to reconsider using "tables" as a variable or column name since it's also the name of a Q built-in function
- it's not clear what the three arguments to your function are, so I did my best to replicate them (the second argument is ignored in my case)

Here goes:

```
// proc1
\p 3737
t1:([] col1:1 2 3; col2:`a`b`c)
t2:([] col1:(.z.D; .z.D); col2:1.0 2.0)
t3:([] colA:4 5 6; colB: (.z.D; .z.D; .z.D); colC:`foo`bar`foo)
configTable: `tables xcol ([] t:`t1`t2`t3)
funcName: {if[z=`metas; : meta x] }



// proc2
h: hopen `::3737
tabs: ?[h "configTable"; (); (); `tables]
{ h (`funcName; x; `tickType; `metas) } each tabs
```